# Node unsupported Platform

Tags: node.js, x86

I am trying to set up my new PC dev environment to match it predecessor, but when I run `NPM install` I get the following error

```
Unsupported platform for node-win-x86@12.22.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x86"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
```

does this suggest that my hardware is inompatible with some node module?

I am unfamiliar with `ia32` and I dont see any option in node installer to install for this particular architecture

Comment: "ia32" is a synonym for 32-bit x86.  Sounds like two pieces of software disagree about naming for what's actually the same thing. :(  See [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320).  (In the Windows world, "x86" usually means specifically 32-bit x86, as opposed to the "x64" term they invented.)

Comment: Assuming you're running Windows on a modern 64-bit processor, It's hard to tell from this info, but I would guess that you're running the 32-bit version of NPM or nodejs and you should have installed the 64-bit version.

Comment: @jfriend00 that was exactly the issue. I inadvertently installed the 32 bit node version. Please create an answer so that I can select as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinBradshaw - Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running Windows on a modern 64-bit processor, it appears that you're running the 32-bit version of NPM or nodejs and you should have installed the 64-bit version.