# Ambiguity in understanding output of platform library in python 3.8

Tags: python, windows, python-3.8, processor, platform

I am using windows 10, I have an intel i5 processor.

I ran the following commands:

```
>>> import platform as p
>>> p.machine()
'AMD64'
>>> p.processor()
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel'
```

Now, with whatever little knowledge I have and reading the [platform library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html), I think `p.machine()` shouldn't have returned `AMD64`, I am positive that I don't have an AMD CPU.

So what's going on here?

What exactly is `platform.machine()`?
(Docs don't really provide a lot of info on this)

Thanks in advance! :)

---

Edit: > Updated the question to make it clearer and removed the i586 reference as per [Gannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17254215/gannon)'s comment

Comment: `AMD64` is an architectur also used by Intel.

Comment: Also `p.machine` specifically look for the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` [environment variables](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/platform.py#L716) values in Windows.

Comment: Ooh thanks a lot, KlausD and Abdul, that helps!

Comment: i586 is Intel Pentium that came out in 1993. I don't think you have a 32 bits architecture. I also don't think you can run Windows 10 on that, but never know :-) AMD64 (x86-64) stands for AMD 64-bits used by AMD, but some Intel 64-bits also work on that architecture

Comment: A follow-up question would be, "architecture" is basically how data moves inside the processor right? So can I assume that inside my `Intel i5` CPU, data moves as per the design/architecture of an `AMD64` CPU?

Comment: @Gannon Not "some", basically all consumer 64-bit  CPUs from Intel are AMD64 after their own 64-bit architecture wasn't a success more than a decade ago.

Comment: @KlausD., to make it really basic and restricting to consumer grade products, Intel didn't really have it's own 64-bit architecture. Intel's EM64T was their own implementation of AMD64, later re-branded to Intel 64. And I will not mention discontinued Itanium :-) ... just a matter of scope.

Comment: I'd guess that running `p.machine(); p.processor()` you get [the same info](https://superuser.com/questions/305901/) as `os.environ ['PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE']; os.environ ['PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER']`, respectively…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs for x86-related CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364320/the-most-correct-way-to-refer-to-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-programs-for-x86)